# SFINAE-enabled function template getting instantiated twice and each time differently

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++17, sfinae

I've designed a **pretty print/format** library using template meta-programming that could print/format objects of any type, as long as they support certain concept(s). For that, I've few overloaded function templates (sfinae-enabled) and I'm using this library in lots of applications. It was working fine using **gcc 4.7.3** with `-std=c++11`.

Now I'm planning to upgrade and use **gcc 7.1.0** & `-std=c++17`. At one place I'm doing equivalent to this:

```
enum class bad_record;

auto s = pretty::format("%1%, %2%", "hello"s, bad_record{});
```

It results in lots of compilation errors, with really *interesting* diagnostic messages; "interesting" because one of the overloaded function template called `try_print_nonptr()` is instantiated **twice** and each time *differently*. First it gets instantiated as expected, i.e `decltype(out << data, void())` is evaluated to be `void`:

```
> $/feut/pretty/details/print_impl.hpp:295:8:   required from 'decltype
> (((out << data), void()))
> feut::pretty::details::try_print_nonptr(std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
> _Traits>&, const Item&, const feut::meta::preference<1>&) [with CharT = char; Traits = std::char_traits<char>; Item = frap::common::bad_record; decltype (((out << data), void())) = void]'
```

and next time, the same expression is evaluated to be `<type-error>`:

```
> /feut/pretty/details/print_impl.hpp: In instantiation of 'decltype
> (((out << data), void()))
> feut::pretty::details::try_print_nonptr(std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
> _Traits>&, const Item&, const feut::meta::preference<1>&) [with CharT = char; Traits = std::char_traits<char>; Item = frap::common::bad_record; decltype (((out << data), void())) = <type
> error>]':
```

I'm unable to reproduce this problem in a small code which I can post here. So I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me understand the scenario(s) in which such an issue could come up, so that I can fix my code accordingly.

The declaration of few overloads are:

```
//this overload is getting instantiated twice
template<typename CharT, typename Traits, typename Item>
auto try_print_nonptr(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits> & out, Item const & data, meta::preference<1> const &) -> decltype(out << data, void());

template<typename CharT, typename Traits, typename Item>
auto try_print_nonptr(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits> & out, Item const & item, meta::preference<2> const &) -> decltype(item.print(out), void());

template<typename CharT, typename Traits, typename Item>
auto try_print_nonptr(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits> & out, Item const & item, meta::preference<3> const &) -> decltype(out << item.to_string(), void());

//there are few more
```

and `preference<N>` is defined as:

```
template<int N> struct preference : preference<N+1> {};

template<> struct preference<25>  {};

using overload_selector = preference<1>;
```

<sup>*more diagnostic messages below; the paths has been shorten and replaced a part with $*</sup>.

```
> $gcc/7.1.0R6/include/c++/7.1.0/ostream:656:5: note: candidate:
> template<class _Ostream, class _Tp> typename
> std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp>
> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>, std::__is_insertable<_Ostream&, const _Tp&, void> >::value, typename
> std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::ostream_type>::type
> std::operator<<(_Ostream&&, const _Tp&)
>      operator<<(_Ostream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
>      ^~~~~~~~
> 
> $gcc/7.1.0R6/include/c++/7.1.0/ostream:656:5: note:   template
> argument deduction/substitution failed:
> $gcc/7.1.0R6/include/c++/7.1.0/ostream: In substitution of
> 'template<class _Ostream, class _Tp> typename
> std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp>
> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>, std::__is_insertable<_Ostream&, const _Tp&, void> >::value, typename
> std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::ostream_type>::type
> std::operator<<(_Ostream&&, const _Tp&) [with _Ostream =
> std::basic_ostream<char>&; _Tp = frap::common::bad_record]':

> $/feut/pretty/details/print_impl.hpp:295:8:   required from 'decltype
> (((out << data), void()))
> feut::pretty::details::try_print_nonptr(std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
> _Traits>&, const Item&, const feut::meta::preference<1>&) [with CharT = char; Traits = std::char_traits<char>; Item = frap::common::bad_record; decltype (((out << data), void())) = void]'
> 
> $/feut/pretty/details/print_impl.hpp:449:20:   required from 'void
> feut::pretty::details::try_print(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&,
> const Item&, const feut::meta::preference<5>&) [with Item =
> frap::common::bad_record; CharT = char; Traits =
> std::char_traits<char>; <template-parameter-1-4> = void]'
> $/feut/pretty/details/object_proxy.hpp:33:22:   required from
> 'std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&
> feut::pretty::proxy_details::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char,
> Traits>&, const feut::pretty::proxy_details::object_proxy<T>&) [with T
> = frap::common::bad_record; CharT = char; Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' $/boost/format/feed_args.hpp:99:12:  
> required from 'void
> boost::io::detail::put_last(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&,
> const T&) [with Ch = char; Tr = std::char_traits<char>; T =
> feut::pretty::proxy_details::object_proxy<frap::common::bad_record>]'
> $/boost/format/feed_args.hpp:126:17:   required from 'void
> boost::io::detail::call_put_last(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&,
> const void*) [with Ch = char; Tr = std::char_traits<char>; T = const
> feut::pretty::proxy_details::object_proxy<frap::common::bad_record>]'
> $/boost/format/feed_args.hpp:135:47:   required from
> 'boost::io::detail::put_holder<Ch, Tr>::put_holder(T&) [with T = const
> feut::pretty::proxy_details::object_proxy<frap::common::bad_record>;
> Ch = char; Tr = std::char_traits<char>]'
> $/boost/format/feed_args.hpp:307:74:   required from
> 'boost::basic_format<Ch, Tr, Alloc>&
> boost::io::detail::feed(boost::basic_format<Ch, Tr, Alloc>&, T) [with
> Ch = char; Tr = std::char_traits<char>; Alloc = std::allocator<char>;
> T = const
> feut::pretty::proxy_details::object_proxy<frap::common::bad_record>&]'
> $/boost/format/format_class.hpp:64:66:   required from
> 'boost::basic_format<Ch, Tr, Alloc>& boost::basic_format<Ch, Tr,
> Alloc>::operator%(const T&) [with T =
> feut::pretty::proxy_details::object_proxy<frap::common::bad_record>;
> Ch = char; Tr = std::char_traits<char>; Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'
> $/feut/pretty/format.hpp:39:16:   required from 'std::string
> feut::pretty::format(const char*, const Args& ...) [with Args =
> {std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
> >, frap::common::bad_record}; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]'
> 
> $/frap/common/sec_analytics_file_reader.cpp:88:83:   required from
> here
> 
> $gcc/7.1.0R6/include/c++/7.1.0/ostream:656:5: error: no type named
> 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_ostream<char>&>'
> 
> $/feut/pretty/details/print_impl.hpp: In instantiation of 'decltype
> (((out << data), void()))
> feut::pretty::details::try_print_nonptr(std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
> _Traits>&, const Item&, const feut::meta::preference<1>&) [with CharT = char; Traits = std::char_traits<char>; Item = frap::common::bad_record; decltype (((out << data), void())) = <type
> error>]':
> 
> $/feut/pretty/details/print_impl.hpp:449:20:   required from 'void
> feut::pretty::details::try_print(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&,
> const Item&, const feut::meta::preference<5>&) [with Item =
> frap::common::bad_record; CharT = char; Traits =
> std::char_traits<char>; <template-parameter-1-4> = void]'
> $/feut/pretty/details/object_proxy.hpp:33:22:   required from
> 'std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&
> feut::pretty::proxy_details::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char,
> Traits>&, const feut::pretty::proxy_details::object_proxy<T>&) [with T
> = frap::common::bad_record; CharT = char; Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' $/boost/format/feed_args.hpp:99:12:  
> required from 'void
> boost::io::detail::put_last(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&,
> const T&) [with Ch = char; Tr = std::char_traits<char>; T =
> feut::pretty::proxy_details::object_proxy<frap::common::bad_record>]'
> $/boost/format/feed_args.hpp:126:17:   required from 'void
> boost::io::detail::call_put_last(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&,
> const void*) [with Ch = char; Tr = std::char_traits<char>; T = const
> feut::pretty::proxy_details::object_proxy<frap::common::bad_record>]'
> $/boost/format/feed_args.hpp:135:47:   required from
> 'boost::io::detail::put_holder<Ch, Tr>::put_holder(T&) [with T = const
> feut::pretty::proxy_details::object_proxy<frap::common::bad_record>;
> Ch = char; Tr = std::char_traits<char>]'
> $/boost/format/feed_args.hpp:307:74:   required from
> 'boost::basic_format<Ch, Tr, Alloc>&
> boost::io::detail::feed(boost::basic_format<Ch, Tr, Alloc>&, T) [with
> Ch = char; Tr = std::char_traits<char>; Alloc = std::allocator<char>;
> T = const
> feut::pretty::proxy_details::object_proxy<frap::common::bad_record>&]'
> $/boost/format/format_class.hpp:64:66:   required from
> 'boost::basic_format<Ch, Tr, Alloc>& boost::basic_format<Ch, Tr,
> Alloc>::operator%(const T&) [with T =
> feut::pretty::proxy_details::object_proxy<frap::common::bad_record>;
> Ch = char; Tr = std::char_traits<char>; Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'
> $/feut/pretty/format.hpp:39:16:   required from 'std::string
> feut::pretty::format(const char*, const Args& ...) [with Args =
> {std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
> >, frap::common::bad_record}; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]'
> 
> $/frap/common/sec_analytics_file_reader.cpp:88:83:   required from
> here
```

Comment: If you're unable to make MCVE, at least give us the code you have. not-so-minimalCVE is better than no code.

Comment: @StoryTeller: If you want code-format instead of quote-format, then I may post the diagnostic messages with the actual `<` and `>` instead of `&lt;` and `&gt;`. That would increase readability!

Comment: @Nawaz - That would be good. As a matter of fact, preferring code to quote also saves you the work of converting the original.

Comment: Also code blocks do scroll. You can put code block *into* a quote if you want.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Posted.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: It's more than few thousands line! I dont think posting that much is even feasible. I tried using a small code, but in that it is not getting reproduced.

Comment: Then post a link? Or even better, bisect it until you get a mcve.

Comment: @Nawaz At least give us the full declaration of `try_print_noptr` and the area around `print_impl.hpp:449`, which is what requires the type-error version.

Comment: @DanielH:  Posted the declarations.